# Google chrome extension how to check if storage is empty?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, storage, google-chrome-storage

How can I check if storage in my google chrome extension is empty? I tried a lot of possibility but nothing worked for me.

Comment: Use `null` for the key name in [.get](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage#method-StorageArea-get), then count the keys in the result with Object.keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fairly simple.

To get the number of bytes of storage currently being used you may use the chrome.storage API.

If you store your extension details in an object called 'settings', you can retrieve the number of bytes being used in the following manner.

```
function logBytes(bytes) {
    console.log(bytes);
}

// gets the number of bytes used in sync storage area
chrome.storage.sync.getBytesInUse(['settings'], logBytes);

// gets the number of bytes used in the local storage area
chrome.storage.local.getBytesInUse(['settings'], logBytes]);
```

The getBytesInUse argument takes an array of strings or a single string, each string representing the keys that store data you wish to count the bytes for.

If your extension is not using any space (empty) you will have zero bytes in use.

Further documentation can be found at [Chrome Storage API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage#type-StorageArea)

Expanding on  wOxxOm's comment, you can get the current objects held in storage by performing the following:

```
function logBytes(bytes) {
    console.log(bytes);
}

function getSyncBytes(settings) {
    var keys = Object.keys(settings);
    chrome.storage.sync.getBytesInUse(keys, logBytes);
}

function getLocalBytes(settings) {
    var keys = Object.keys(settings);
    chrome.storage.local.getBytesInUse(keys, logBytes);
}

chrome.storage.sync.get(null, getSyncBytes);
chrome.storage.local.get(null, getLocalBytes);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! You wouldn't believe how long I was studying this problem!

Comment: @Doppler Not a problem! I just expanded the answer showing how to get ALL space used by your extension by expanding on wOxxOm's comment.